# Limit to the number of results from a Dataflow input file pattern glob?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Update:

We've seen these 400-class errors re:

`com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request { "code" : 400, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Request payload exceeds the allowable limit: 50000.", "reason" : "badRequest" } ], "message" : "Request payload exceeds the allowable limit: 50000.", "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145) at`

on a glob that resolves to:

`TOTAL: 60 objects, 8405391 bytes (8.02 MiB)`

and have been experiencing increased variability of input globs hitting the limit over the past several days.

--

Recently we've had observations of job failure when filepattern specs that derive to large numbers of files are passed as the input to Dataflow jobs.  Examples of the messages produced in these scenarios are:

```
Apr 29, 2015, 9:22:51 AM
(5dd3e79031bdcc45): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request { "code" : 400, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Request payload exceeds the allowable limit: 50000.", "reason" : "badRequest" } ], "message" : "Request payload exceeds the allowable limit: 50000.", "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321) at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$DataflowWorkUnitClient.reportWorkItemStatus(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:273) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.reportStatus(DataflowWorker.java:209) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:157) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:95) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:139) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:124) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 9:22:51 AM
 Failed task is going to be retried.
```

We've had some success with job parallelization in response to this, but were wondering if there was a hard limit or quota somewhere that is being run into.  The retried tasks inevitably fail after the maximum # of retries is reached then causing the job to fail.

Thanks!

Sal

Comment: Some additional salient error messages:  `Failed to split source. Causes: (9a576143e1c9f188): Task has been attempted unsuccessfully 4 times, the maximum allowed.` `Request payload exceeds the allowable limit: 50000`

Comment: This is a bug in the service and a fix should be rolled out shortly. I'll keep you posted. Meanwhile, how many files does your filepattern expand into?

Comment: between 2000 and 25000 I believe we've had issues with.  Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Thanks. I'll notify you when it's time to try running again.

Comment: It appears as if the limitation is more a function of the total number of bytes across all files yielded by the wildcard as opposed to the total number of individual files yielded on match.  Can you confirm?

Comment: The limitation is a function of the number of bytes in the reportWorkItemStatus RPC (https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/dataflow/v1beta3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/dataflow/model/ReportWorkItemStatusRequest.html). When a Source splits via splitIntoBundles, the bundles are currently transmitted to the service in one RPC (we're considering changing this).

Comment: Okay, it should be fine to try again. Please tell me if you see any issues.

Answer (score 1):

The Dataflow service has been updated to handle larger requests of this type, and should no longer produce this issue.